# Speed issues with while loops from file

Tags: bash

This script, even though it works, it takes too much longer to execute in large files, due to the while loops, but I could not think of any faster way to go thru the files. Any suggestions to improve its speed if welcome.

I have a list like this. This is how the objFile input looks like:

```
    object-group network AES_PCH_CONGONHAL_CCEEP
     network-object host 1.1.1.1
    object-group network aes-LANTRONIX
     description LANTRONIX
     network-object object AES_PCH_CONGONHAL_CCEEP
     network-object object AES_PCH_CONGONHAL_CCEER
```

This is the IP looks like:

```
1.1.1.1
aes-LANTRONIX
```

I need to search for a IP list and bring back all 'object-group or 'object' the IP is in and the full content of each object. For instance, IP 1.1.1.1. The output should look like this

```
object-group network AES_PCH_CONGONHAL_CCEEP
 network-object host 1.1.1.1
```

This could be recursive, having a object inside a object, that`s why a have an array for further looking

```
function findVar {

    while read ip
    do
        local flag=0
     while read objFile
     do
        if ! echo $objFile |grep -q -e '^object-group\|^object'
        then
        local allip+=" $objFile\n"
            if echo $objFile | grep -q -e "$ip$\|$ip\ "
            then
            local objectNAME=$(echo $object | cut -d' ' -f3)
            grep access-list $showrunn | grep -e "$objectNAME\|$ip " >> $acl
            tempV+=("$objectNAME")
            flag=1
            fi
        else
        if [ $flag -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo $object
            echo -e "$allip"
            unset allip
            flag=0
        else
            unset allip
        fi
        object=$(echo $objFile |grep -e '^object-group\|^object')
        fi
     done <<< "$(cat $1)"
    done <<< "$(cat $2)"
}

num_words=${#tempV[@]}
for i in "${!tempV[@]}"; do
    findVar "$objBKP" "$var"
done
```

Comment: You're using a lot of external programs like `cut` and `grep` when `bash` itself has builtin tools to do the same thing. Not really a performance issue, but you're using `<<<` when a simple input redirection would work: `while ...; do ... done < "$1"`. Given that your primary problem is that your code is too slow, I think this is a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You say (I think) that you could be looking for a host like `1.1.1.1` but also a group like `aes-LANTRONIX`, those are two different types of object, how can they be handled the same?

Comment: If you want speed, bash is the wrong tool. I'd choose perl. If you want a fast POSIX-based shell, use ksh93

Comment: You have to be careful with regular expressions in bash. When you put regex metachars (`$`, `|`) in quotes, they lose their special meaning and are treated as plain literal characters

Comment: `<<< "$(cat $1)"` as @chepner pointed out.  But I feel that could be a performance issue in that it will read the entire file into memory, rather than a line at a time.  Use `< "$1"` instead.  Many of the external programs are unnecessary.

Comment: @cdarke. Good point; I was focusing on the overhead of starting so many unnecessary processes.

Comment: @chepner:  and you were right to.  I didn't wish to imply that the external processes are not a problem.  Bad performance is often caused by a combination of issues rather than just one bad practice.

Comment: I would like to refactor your code and run some performance tests, but your code is not a runnable example.  Could you clarify what `tempV` is?  Is `objBKP` the name of the objFile?  What is `var`?

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` to the rescue!

a prototype solution for the given structure can be

```
$ gawk -v RS="object-group" '/1\.1\.1\.1/{print RT $0}' file

object-group network AES_PCH_CONGONHAL_CCEEP
     network-object host 1.1.1.1
```

I'm not sure I understand your nested structure and what you expect as output in that case.

Note that you need multi-char RS, which is not available in all awks.

Comment: Note you'd want to make RS "object-group network"; this is a Cisco config file and there are a few different types of object groups.

Comment: yes, probably many other things as well, just wanted to add `gawk` as an alternative to heavy bash scripting.